# JCasC - configure a hudson.security.SecurityRealm

Tags: jenkins, jcasc

Im trying to configure Jenkins helm chart of jenkinsci with JCasC.

this is part of my value.yml

```
  JCasC:
    defaultConfig: true
    securityRealm: |-
      saml:
        binding: "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        displayNameAttributeName: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
        emailAttributeName: "email"
        groupsAttributeName: "group"
        idpMetadataConfiguration:
          url: ""
          period: 0
      maximumAuthenticationLifetime: 2073600
      usernameAttributeName: "username"
      usernameCaseConversion: "none"
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong but im getting this error from jenkins:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Single entry map expected to configure a hudson.security.SecurityRealm
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.configureMapping(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:291)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.preConfigure(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:273)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.configure(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:83)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.check(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:92)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.check(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:55)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:360)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:293)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.lambda$checkWith$9(ConfigurationAsCode.java:803)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:737)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:803)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:789)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:658)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:315)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:307)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:115)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:185)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1166)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:290)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1201)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:989)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:264)
```

I tried couple of changes but nothing is working.

anyone encounter an issue like this?

I did configure everything manually and its working fine but with JCasC it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious point of failure is that the last three lines should be indented to match with the idpMetadataConfiguration line, it looks like.

The error is telling you that the YML config for 'securityrealm' wants a map with only one entry, but the indentation on those three lines is read as 3 additional entries.